# Fining the sum of a series .

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm solving a probability problem and the expected value of a random variable is this series I need some hint to find the sum of it.

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$

Comment: differentiate the geometric series. afterwards put $x=1/2$

Comment: [Here](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202005%20-%20finite%20calculus.pdf) you have a general technique to evaluate these sums.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For $x\in(-1,1)$,  we have

$$x+2x^2+3x^3+...=x(1+2x+3x^2+...)$$

$$=x\frac{d(x+x^2+x^3+...)}{dx}$$

$$=\frac{x}{1-x}+\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}$$

Now, you choose the right $x$.